# common_msgs package missing sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py in Groovy/Precise?

Tags: sensor-msgs, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The github repo for common_msgs/sensor_msgs contains a point_cloud2.py that looks useful for accessing the data in PointCloud2 messages in Python, however it doesn't seem to get installed when you install the common_msgs from debs using Groovy/Precise. Is it deprecated or something? Is there another way to get the data from a pointcloud2 in Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64836/common_msgs-package-missing-sensor_msgs/point_cloud2.py-in-groovy/precise?/) by [JonWeisz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5120/jonweisz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right. It looks like that module was forgotten in the catkin conversion.

Please [open an issue](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/issues/new) to get that fixed. You can link back to this question to avoid repeating stuff.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-11**:
Looks like the documentation for that module is also missing.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-07-14**:
https://github.com/ros/common_msgs/issues/11